# How can I load plist files from ActionScript?

Tags: actionscript-3, plist

Is there any library for loading plist files from ActionScript?

Does it supports binary format for plist files?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ByteArray](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html) to handle binary data.

Comment: LOL, I have no intentions to implement plist parsing myself, thanks.